# How to handle StringIndexOutOfBoundException in this code

Tags: java

I searched existing database but could not find the answer for my question below .
The code runs fine but it throws stringIndexOutOfBoundException.

```
public class CountingValleys {
    static void countingValleyscount(int n, String s) {
        s="UUDDUDUU";
        n=8;
        int i=0;
        int v=0;
        System.out.println("Entering the program");
        while( i<s.length())
        {
            while(s.charAt(i)=='U'&& i<s.length())
            {
                ++i;
                v++;
            }
            while(s.charAt(i)=='D')
            {
                i=i+1;
                v--;
            }
            if(v==0)
                System.out.println("Reached Sea Level");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n = 0;
        String s = null;
        CountingValleys.countingValleyscount( n,  s);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it throws an Exception, then it does not run fine.  Why do you think that checking the bounds `&& i<s.length()` is not necessary for the second while loop?  If you debugged your code you would soon find the error.

Comment: I would step back and think about what you're doing here. You have three `while` loops, each of them using the same `i` variable to check, two of them altering `i`. I can't make a decent guess as to what would be a proper code fix here, but the exception is thrown in the 3rd while loop – `while (s.charAt(i) == 'D') { .. }` – it reaches that loop a few times, including the last time when `i` is 8, then your code fails with `s.charAt(8)`.

Comment: @Scary Wombat adding i<s.length() in second while does not fix the error . The exception is thrown at the first while ie while(s.charAt(i)=='U'&& i<s.length()).

Comment: The code is evaluated *left* to *right*, so you probably want to put `i<s.length()` first

Comment: getting same exception even when I  put i<s.length() first

Comment: @ScaryWombat it worked when (i<s.length()) was moved left . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs in the second while loop,when the `i=7`,The second while loop condition is true,then `i=8`,`s.charAt(8)` while throw

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException;

The last：you can use idea's or eclipse's debug mode

Comment: Yes I did use the debug mode and I know exactly where the problem is but I am trying to find an efficient solution to fix the problem

Comment: while (i < s.length() && s.charAt(i) == 'U' && i < s.length()) {
                ++i;
                v++;
            }
            while (i < s.length() && s.charAt(i) == 'D') {
                i = i + 1;
                v--;
            }

Is that ok？